# Some photos appear way too dark in Google Picasa but are fine in other apps

Tags: macos, picasa

Some photographers photos are appearing as excessively dark in Picasa. No other photo viewing application is having this issue. I have tried turning off Color Management in the settings but it still has the issue.

I am using the latest Picasa 3.8.9.390 on Mac OS X Mavericks but have had this problem for a long time over many versions.

Comment: I don't think you can turn this off. It's one of the reasons I stopped using Picasa. It was very pronounced in over/underexposed raw photos (I believe it creates a "fixed" jpeg version to actually render on screen) though it seemed all my JPGs looked a bit darker also.